# React-bootstrap (1.0.0-beta16) Carousel not working in Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, carousel, react-bootstrap

My React application is using react-bootstrap's carousel.  The carousel works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge but does not work on Internet Explorer.

**Issue: The carousel will switch the first time then freezes. It no longer automatically switches, and you can not click on the indicators to change page.**

I have searched online and here and can not find a post/solution for my specific case.

My package.json shows which version on React-Bootstrap that i am using

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "~5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "~3.2.0",
    "react-tabs": "^3.1.0"
  },
```

I am specifying to use polyfills as the first imports in my index.js

```
// these 2 MUST be the first 2 imports
import "react-app-polyfill/ie11";
import "react-app-polyfill/stable";
```

A simplified version of my render method is

```
    return (
        <div >
            <Carousel interval="2000" >
                {this.state.carouselItemsArr.map(
                    (item, i) =>
                        <Carousel.Item key={i}>
                            <img src={item.image} alt="first" />
                            <Carousel.Caption>
                                <div className="...">
                                    {item.name}
                                </div>
                            </Carousel.Caption>
                        </Carousel.Item>
                )}
            </Carousel>                
        </div>
    );
```

*Solutions tried*

Ideally I would like to get the carousel working in Internet Explorer.  If I can not get it working, then an acceptable work around is to show the first item in the carousel, not switch to any other and hide the indicators.

I can hide the indicators using JavaScript, but this does not stop the carousel switching once before freezing.

```
var showIndicators = (this._isIE) ? false : true;

 return (
     <div>
         <Carousel interval="2000" indicators={showIndicators}>
   ....
```

I tried hiding the indicators using css, but as soon as i add the media query (even if its empty) the whole site no longer renders in IE. Furthermore like the JavaScript workaround above it does not stop the carousel switching once.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* IE10+ CSS */
    .carousel-indicators {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it show any error message in the console of the IE browser? I can see that your jS code has Arrow functions => in it which is not supported in the IE browser. You can try to use Bebel.js to convert your ES6 code to ES5 code. We are not able to produce the issue using the above code because it is not a complete code. If possible you can try to create JSFiddle example which we can try to run and check. It can help to narrow downt the issue.

Comment: I am using polyfill so the arrow functions should be ok to use

Comment: Another workaround is to identify the IE browser using code and replace the carousel with an image tag or load the carousel dynamically based on browser user opened. If your issue still persists, I suggest you post an example using JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to always ensure the "activeIndex" is 0 when the browser is IE.  This stops the Carousel from switching between indexes.  When the callback is fired when the active item is changed (onSelect), if the browser is IE do not change the active index. Therefore for IE the active index is always 0 (the first item) and therefore the Carousel never slides and simply appears like an image rather than the carousel.

```
export default class CarouselComponent extends React.Component {

     // determine if the browser is IE
     _isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; 

    state = {
        activeIndex : 0
        carouselItemsArr: null,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         // gets carousel items from server
         // var carouselItemsArr = .....
         self.setState({
             carouselItemsArr: items,
         });
    }

    /**
     * Callback fired when the active item changes.
     * If the browser is IE, do not change the activeIndex, 
     * therefore the carousel will not switch items
     */
    handleActiveItemChange = (selectedIndex, e) => {
         if (!this._isIE) {
            this.setState({
                activeIndex : selectedIndex,
            });
         }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Carousel interval="2000" 
                      activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex} 
                      onSelect={this.handleActiveItemChange}>

                {this.state.carouselItemsArr.map(
                     .....
                )}

            </Carousel>                
        </div>
    );
```